# ¿Como conectarme a Mysql remote?

Tags: mysql, c#, asp.net

Estoy tratando de conectarme a mi bd en mi cpanel desde mi aplicacion net core, pero sigo sin poder conectarme, realice los siguientes pasos:

1. Cree la BD en mi cpanel.

   - A esa base de datos le cree un usuario con todos los privilegios.
   - Despues en el apartado `Remote MySQL` cree un `Access Host` con la IP de mi computadora.
   - Coloque las credenciales en mi cadena de conexión `Server=server; Port= 3306; User ID=corpo131; Database=corpo131_AMLCC; Password=pasword`
2. En mi Server coloque la IP que sale en mi `Geneal information` de mi cpanel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En mi `User ID` coloque el usuario creado con los privilegios
  asignados.
- En mi `Password` coloque el del usuario creado.

Me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay algo en lo que me este equivocando? o Si tengo que administrar en mi equipo? Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Para verificar que no sea problema con tu IP cambia en Host en Cpanel por % y prueba nuevamente. (el % te permite conectarte de cualquier lado)

Comment: No, sigue sin dejarme! Eliminé los host que tenia y creé uno solo como me dijiste, con el signo de %

Comment: Puedes hacer lo siguiente.. prueba tu conexión acá https://phpmyadmin.co/ y si logras entrar allí vas descartando que no sea cosa de permisos remotos. (Recuerda Cambiar tu clave luego de probar por seguridad)

Comment: Ya lo realice y me sale el mismo error o `o el zócalo local al servidor MySQL no está configurado correctamente`.

Comment: Es cosa de permisos, allí puedes probar si de verdad tienes acceso a Mysql Remoto, puedes ir verificando y probando. Otra cosa puede ser que tu hosting no permita remoto, verifica con tu soporte en ese caso para que estés seguro

Comment: Muchas gracias Josue. Haré eso de ver con soporte.

Comment: Hay muchas herramientas Online para que pruebes, una de ella es https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/ alli te registras gratis, si tu BD es menor a 5MB de peso, crea una y ellos te dan el remoto, con eso pruebas si tu código funciona y ya luego te concentras en el Cpanel. Saludos y Suerte | Edit: Alli las bd las borran a los días, solo es para pruebas :)